# Limpiar la consola tras cada ejecucion del while principal

Tags: python, python-3.x, consola

Buenas amigos. El hecho es el siguiente, tengo un pequeño código del juego ahorcados, sin embargo cada vez que se ejecuta su funcion principal va avanzando hacia abajo dejando la anterior accion arriba como es tipico en la terminal. Quisiera que se limpiara después de ingresar una letra. Pq si no se acumulan todos los intentos y se llena la terminal y es un poco confuso. aqui el codigo. Agradecería su ayuda

```
import random
import os

IMAGENES=["A  ","AH  ","AHO  ","AHOR  ","AHORC  ","AHORCA  ","AHORCAD  
","AHORCADO  "]
PALABRAS=[
"lavadora",
"secadora",
"sofa",
"gobierno",
"computadora",
"cubo",
"paralelepipedo"
]

def randomWord():
    indiceAlea=random.randint(0,len(PALABRAS)-1)
    return PALABRAS[indiceAlea]

def displayBoard(hiddenWord,intentos):
    print(IMAGENES[intentos])
    print("")
    print(hiddenWord)   
    print("--- * ---- --- * ---- --- * ---- --- * ---- --- * ---- --- * ----
    ")

def body():
    word=randomWord()
    hiddenWord=["_"]*len(word)
    intentos=0

letrasUsadas=[]
while True:
    displayBoard(hiddenWord,intentos)
    letraIntro=str(input("Escoge una letra:  "))
    letrasUsadas.append(letraIntro)
    print("Ya ha utilizado las siguientes letras",letrasUsadas)
    listLetras=[]
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i]==letraIntro:
            listLetras.append(i)
    if len(listLetras)==0:
        intentos+=1

        if intentos==8:
            print("")
            print("Usted ha perdido, la palabra era",word)
            break
    else:
        for i in listLetras:
            hiddenWord[i]=letraIntro
        listLetras=[]
    os.system("cls")

    try:
        hiddenWord.index("_")
    except ValueError:
        print("")
        print("Felicidades, has ganado, la pabra es",word)
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("B  I  E  N  V  E  N  I  D  O    A     A  H  O  R  C  A  D  O")


    body()
```

Algo asi como limpiar la terminal manualmente como seria en windows con cls. Pero que lo hago el mismo programa despues de cada iteracion del ciclo while principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu script se ejecuta en la consola de Windows puedes usar *`cls`* tal como dices mediante el módulo `os` de la biblioteca estándar:

```
import os

for _ in range(5):
    input('Ingrese algo:  ')
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: En Linux/OSX es `clear`.

Comment: Efectivamente Toledano, solo que hay que tener en cuenta que  `clear ` es un proceso externo que no limpia el buffer de la terminal (podemos hacer scroll hacia arriba y ver las líneas anteriores) mientras que  `cls ` en Windows es una función propia de la consola que implicitamente limpia el buffer.

Comment: Me ha servido. Pero por ejemplo. Tengo una lista que muestra que letras ya ha introducido el usuario. Y al utilizar os.system("cls") me limpia incluso esa lista. No se porque. Alguna idea¡?

Comment: @limg21 eso no debería afectarte para nada en ese aspecto. Si quieres puedes editar la pregunta añadiendo el código actual a ver si vemos lo que pasa. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla Ya acabo de editar el nueco codigo amigo. tengo dos probelmas ahora y es que quise crear una lista e imprimirla para que el usuario viera que letras ya ha ingresado. pero despues de cada ejecucion del while principal se vacia la lista y solo me muestra la anterior letra introducida. Encima de esto la funcion os.system("cls") me borra esa lista cuando la imprimo. Si ejecutas el codigo te daras cuenta

Comment: @limg21 se vacia porque la estas creando de nuevo en cada iteración del `while` al hacer `letrasUsadas=[]`, para que guarde las letras debes hacer esto fuera del ciclo `while` y dentro de el solo usas append, pero la lista la creas fuera. No se si es un error al pegar, pero ¿el `while` no deberia ir dentro de la función `body`?.

Comment: @FJSevilla Si amigo fue un error de copiar y pegar . El while esta dentro de body. ya he actilizado el codigo. Y se soluciono el problema de la lista. Ahora si me lo guara, la estaba inicializando en cada ejecucion, Pero ahora es que cada vez que se ejecuta el while y a su ves el os.system("cls") me sigue borrando por pantalla de la consola esa funcion de mostrame las letras usadas, No se donde estoy fallando

Comment: @FJSevilla no se si es la mejor manera de solucionarlo pero lo consegui. puse a que me imprimiera por pantalla la lista de letras usadas despues de limpiar la terminal

Answer (score 0):

yo estoy haciendo algo similar pero un poco mas anticuada mi programacion, se puede borrar la terminal para que no se vea la palabra clave o a adivinar. ahorita no esta terminado ni muy estructurado aun me falta programar para letras que se repiten y solo funciona hasta 6 letras.

```
palabra_clave = input("Dame la palabra secreta: ")

print("Palabra de " , len(palabra_clave) , " letras")
cuenta = len(palabra_clave)
palabra_prueba = ""
i = 0
while i in range(cuenta):
    palabra_prueba = palabra_prueba + palabra_clave[i] + " "
    i += 1
palabra_prueba = palabra_prueba[0 : (cuenta*2)-1]
#print(palabra_prueba)
palabra_concatenada = ""
i = 0

for i in range(cuenta):
    palabra_concatenada = palabra_concatenada + "_" + " "

print(palabra_concatenada)
errores = 1

while errores <=6 and palabra_concatenada != palabra_prueba:
    letra_prueba = input("Dame una letra: ")
    existe = palabra_clave.count(letra_prueba)

if existe:
    letra_doble = (palabra_clave.count(letra_prueba))
    if letra_doble >= 2:
        letra1 = palabra_clave.index(letra_prueba)
        letra2 = palabra_clave.rindex(letra_prueba)
        print(letra1)
        print(letra2)


    else:
        letra1 = palabra_clave.index(letra_prueba)
        print (letra1)
        if letra1 == 0:
            palabra_concatenada = palabra_clave[0] + palabra_concatenada[1 : len(palabra_concatenada)-1]
            print(palabra_concatenada)
        elif letra1 == 1:
            palabra_concatenada = palabra_concatenada[0 : 2] + palabra_clave[1] + palabra_concatenada[3 : len(palabra_concatenada)]
            print(palabra_concatenada)
        elif letra1 == 2:
            palabra_concatenada = palabra_concatenada[0 : 4] + palabra_clave[2] + palabra_concatenada[5 : len(palabra_concatenada)]
            print(palabra_concatenada)
        elif letra1 == 3:
            palabra_concatenada = palabra_concatenada[0: 6] + palabra_clave[3] + palabra_concatenada[7 : len(palabra_concatenada)]
            print(palabra_concatenada)
        elif letra1 == 4:
            palabra_concatenada = palabra_concatenada[0 : 8] + palabra_clave[4] + palabra_concatenada[9 : len(palabra_concatenada)]
            print(palabra_concatenada)
        elif letra1 == 5:
            palabra_concatenada = palabra_concatenada[0 : 10] + palabra_clave[5] + palabra_concatenada[11 : len(palabra_concatenada)]
            print(palabra_concatenada)


else:
    print("Esa letra no existe XD ")
    print("llevas " , errores , " errores")
    print(palabra_concatenada)
    errores = errores + 1
letra1 = ""
letra2 = ""
#index = palabra_clave.index(letra_prueba)
#print(index)


if errores >=6:
    print("Ahorcado")
else:
    print("Ganaste")
```

Comment: entonces ya es la respuesta final?