# Limpiar interprete en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, terminal

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de limpiar la terminal cuando uso el interprete de Python3.
Investigué en internet y todos recomiendan usar el modulo os y, para limpiar la terminal, ejecutar la linea

```
os.system("cls")
```

ya que uso windows.

El problema es que cuando lo implemento en mi codigo y lo ejecuto no hace nada.
Luego, cuando ejecuto solamente esa linea en el interprete de Python3 me devuelve

> -1

Se les ocurre como resolver el problema o por qué se debe que devuelva "-1"?
Gracias!

Comment: si usted pone os.system("cls") no debe devolver nada ya que usted no pidio ninguna devolucion

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Limpiar la consola tras cada ejecucion del while principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71551/limpiar-la-consola-tras-cada-ejecucion-del-while-principal)

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando un IDLE (como Netbeans, Pycharm, etc)?

os.system("cls") no funciona correctamente en muchos IDLEs. Prueba a ejecutar tu programa desde un terminal cmd (ya que estas utilizando windows), haciendo `python3 myprograma`, debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Nope, lo estoy ejecutando desde la terminal cmd de windows de la forma en que vos me decis.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ejecutando el cmd como administrador y luego abriendo la aplicación. Claramente el "-1" significa que hubo un error. Quizás python no pudo ejecutar el comando por alguna razón.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente python a tenido problema ejecutando el modulo.
prueba instalando el modulo de nuevo os-sys `pip install os-sys` , aca te dejo la documentacion del modulo para que puedas mirar como funciona https://pypi.org/project/os-sys/ espero haber sido de ayuda gracias por mirar el comentario